# Retrieving sql database information with PHP prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm looking to find the username in the table and take the full first name and surname, concatenate and bind to a variable ($usernames). This is a snippet of code from a larger login file where $link etc is defined, and the connection is working:

```
$param_username = "x";
$users_fname = $users_sname = "";
$sql = "SELECT users_fname, users_sname FROM users WHERE users_username = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $users_fname, $users_sname);
$usernames = $users_fname . $users_sname;

$_SESSION["username"] = $usernames;
echo  $_SESSION["username"];
```

Can anyone spot what I might have gotten wrong?

The statement being executed seems to return the row/columns just fine when run on the database directly, i.e:

```
SELECT users_fname, users_sname FROM users WHERE users_username = 'x';
```

Comment: You need to use mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt) in a while loop to retrieve the results after binding the results.  See Example #2 Procedural style  here:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php    THEN learn the object-oriented style and start doing it that way.

Comment: I find that people generally find `PDO` easier to use than `mysqli_*`. If you are having a hard time grapsing `mysqli_*`, I recommend switching to `PDO`.

Comment: You never fetch anything from the server. You must use `get_result()` to get the result.

Comment: Thanks to all, the code works for now, but I'm looking at PDO and object oriented as better ways to approach the bigger code sections l'll need soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line :

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $users_fname, $users_sname);
```

Add:

```
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
```

Then:

```
 $usernames = $users_fname . $users_sname;
 $_SESSION["username"] = $usernames;
 echo  $_SESSION["username"];
```

Comment: Thank you Hardood! That solved my problem! :)

Comment: Glad to help you. So please locate the correct mark on the top left side of the answer and click it to say it is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You never fetch anything from the server. You must use `get_result()` to get the result.

```
$param_username = "x";
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(users_fname, users_sname) AS fullname FROM users WHERE users_username = ?";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param_username);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$_SESSION["username"] = $data[0]['fullname'];
```

I do not recommend using `bind_result()`, but if you want to do it using this function then you can do it the following way:

```
$param_username = "x";
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(users_fname, users_sname) AS fullname FROM users WHERE users_username = ?";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param_username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($_SESSION["username"]);
$stmt->fetch(); // execute for each row if you have more than 1
```

Using PDO this would be much faster.

Comment: Thank you Dharman! Just looking at your code, does this use an object oriented style? If so, can I combine it with the database link I created procedurally?

Comment: Yes and yes. But OO style is more readable. For readability don't mix them.